# Выводить дату в русскоязычном формате

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, локализация

В приложении asp.net core mvc в представлениях часто приходится выводить даты в кратком формате:

```
<td>@transfer.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
```

При этом у меня на компьютере даты отображаются как ДД.ММ.ГГГГ, а при заливке на appharbor даты выводятся в формате ММ/ДД/ГГГГ

Приложение рассчитано исключительно на русскоязычных пользователей, поэтому хочется один раз задать формат для всех пользователей. Возможности ставить/настраивать локали на appharbor у меня нет.

Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подсмотрел решение на en so [How to set culture for date binding in Asp.Net Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44688311/5752652)

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var supportedCultures = new[] { new CultureInfo("ru-RU") };
        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("ru-RU"),
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
        });
        ...
```